# Gazebo plugin vs. pr2_mechanism

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, plugin, pr2-controllers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to create simulation of simple robot and play with it little. I have (almost) working URDF model a now I have to write some controller. But I'm little bit confused...

First I tried to study how to write Gazebo controller (or plugin?), but documentation is quite poor. Now I'm studying pr2_mechanism stack - it's much better documented and looks like easier way for me.

So my question - what is main difference between robot controller written as Gazebo plugin or as pr2_controller? Which way is encouraged? Is there any important disadvantage when using pr2_controller? Is it possible to use just it without any gazebo plugin?

Thanks for any advice or opinion.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11425/gazebo-plugin-vs.-pr2_mechanism/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2011-10-05

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using the pr2_mechanism model is preferred because it provides a ROS interace to Gazebo. Without this interface, you have no acess to the information from your ROS nodes. The pr2_mechanism stack provides some good tutorials for writing your own controller. A tutorial can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2